# How to copy files into root directory using GUI

Tags: permissions, nautilus, files

I am trying to get permission access to get root access for copying files to root directory using Graphical user interface. 
I have tried

```
gksudo nautilus
```

but I got an error

> (gksudo:5334): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I have also tried

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

but I got the same error ...I am using ubuntu 17.10. Kindly help me out. Thanks

Comment: great :) glad it helped.